# Handing Firebase + Facebook login process

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have Facebook Login in my app, and I'm running in circles trying to get a balance to new users needing to go through the signup screen, and registered users who should just be taken straight into the app. This is the function for handling Facebook Login (when the button is tapped and Facebook authorizes):

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    if error != nil {
        return
    }
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "name"]).start { (connection, result, err) in

        let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current()
        guard let accessTokenString = accessToken?.tokenString else {return}
        let credentials = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessTokenString)

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in

            if error != nil {
                return
            }
            if(FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil){
                // logged in
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToRooms", sender: nil)
            }else{
                // not logged in
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showSetupScreen", sender: nil)
            }
        })

        if err != nil {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

In the `FIRAuth.auth` block above, I basically say that once the Facebook Login button is tapped and goes through the Facebook authorization, if the user has an access token, go straight into the app. Otherwise, go to the sign-up screen where the user will enter the necessary information.

I also have this in `viewDidLoad`, so when the app is launched, if the user was previously logged in, they won't even see the login screen, they'll just go straight into the app:

```
    // When app is launched, bring user straight in if they're already authorized. Otherwise show the login screen.
    FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
        if let user = user {
            // User is signed in. Show home screen
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToRooms", sender: nil)
        } else {
            // No User is signed in. Show user the login screen
            return
        }
    }
```

However I've found during testing that if I tap the Facebook Login and enter Facebook credentials as a new user, I get authorized and then sent straight into the app, without going through the signup screen. This causes all sorts of problems.

For those of you who use Facebook Login with Firebase, what's a good way to handle this situation? I need to cover a few scenarios:

1. If a new user taps the Facebook Login button, they will be taken to the signup screen.
2. If a registered (but logged out) user taps the Facebook Login button, they will be taken straight into the app.
3. If a registered, still logged-in user launches the app, they will bypass the login screen and be taken straight into the app.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's a little unclear what the intention is; if a user *authenticates* with Facebook, then well, they are authenticated. Are you trying to let them authenticate with Facebook and then a separate 'sign up' process to access the app data?

Comment: I think - as I said at the end of my question, I need to handle those three scenarios. Currently if a user is logged in and doesn't log out, the app correctly launches when opened, bypassing both login and signup screens. Also, if a user logs out, then launches the app, they'll see the login screen. Then if they tap on the Facebook Login button, they'll be "remembered" and go straight into the app. However with my current code, if a new user comes along and taps the Facebook button, they'll go straight into the app without hitting the signup screen.

Comment: I thought my "else" condition to segue to the signup screen would handle that issue but unfortunately it doesn't. I'm not sure how to handle all three scenarios.

Comment: Can you clarify your comment; *if a new user comes along and taps the Facebook button*. What defines them as a new user?

Comment: Yeah I think this is where the confusion comes in - a new user, to me, would be someone who has not signed up for my app before (i.e. would not be in Firebase).

Comment: Currently I think tapping the Facebook button is verifying that they have a Facebook account, and if so, they are authorized, and thus go straight into the app instead of the signup screen. When in fact I need the check to be whether or not the user had an account with my app (Firebase I guess). If so, go straight in. If not, go to the signup screen.

Comment: The only time that would happen is if uid_0 is authenticated on his phone but not in the app and uid_1 grabs the phone, runs down the street and taps your app - which would then authenticate using uid_0's account. A true new user would be one that just downloaded the app and is running it for the first time. Yes? If not, maybe some more information about the flow and what makes a new user new could be added to your question.

Comment: Yes! Sorry, re-reading my answer to your question, that wasn't clear. A new user is someone who is signing up for my app for the first time. So when a new user taps the Facebook button on the login screen, I need the signup screen to be shown. When a registered user (someone who has already authorized with Firebase) taps the button on the login screen (if they have logged out of the app), they should be taken straight into the app without hitting the signup screen. And finally when a registered user launches the app, if they never logged out, they should bypass BOTH the login and signup screen

Comment: So lets explore a bit. If an existing user logs in, and then logs out, Firebase deauthenticates the user. If they purposefully logged out it shouldn't just auto-log them back in; that would be a security issue and force you to keep their credentials lying around (forgetting auto-fill for the moment). If they log out, that should be it - they should have to re-enter their credentials to log back in. Otherwise there would be no purpose of logging out. On the other hand, if they are using the app and say, want to take a call, the app keeps them logged in so they can go right back to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145151/discussion-between-kingtim-and-jay).

Comment: We can take it to chat if it's easier, I'm already in there. Anyway, I'm thinking of a login process like Tinder, where if I log out of the app, then come back to it, I'm presented with the login screen (with the Facebook Login button). If I tap that button, I'll get authenticated with Facebook and be taken into the app, with all my user info in place right where I left off.

Comment: However if I'm a new user who has just downloaded the app for the first time, and I tap the Facebook button of the login screen, I'll be presented with a signup screen where I enter some info about myself.

Comment: And then the third scenario is that I download the app and sign up, then never log out. If I close and re-open the app, I will still be signed in (i.e. I will be taken straight into the app without seeing either the login or signup screens).

Comment: As for the security concerns, let's just say for arguments sake that anyone with user 1's phone can log into user 1's account by simply opening the app (if user 1 never logged out) or by tapping the Facebook login button on the login screen (if user 1 did log out). It is technically a security concern however if we're being honest, that's why people have fingerprint/passcode access to their phones!

Comment: It seems there are only two possibilities; an existing user (that may be logged in or not logged in) and a new user. If the existing user is logged in and they take a call, when they go back to the app they are still logged in, so that's easy. If the existing user logs out then taps the app they are presented with a screen that asks for their login credentials (with a button to create an account for new users). So, then you verify their credentials and log them in or sign them up as a new user via the create account button. You could add an auto-logout after x minutes feature as well!

Comment: There are no login credentials, it's Facebook login only. The existing user scenarios work already, as I said a user who never logs out will always be logged in, whether they take a call, or close the app then reopen it. Also if an existing user logs out, then opens the app, they're shown the login screen with the Facebook button and tapping it authenticates them with Facebook and they're brought into the app. All working well. However I need to check, when the Facebook button is tapped, whether or not the user is a new user, or an existing user who has logged out.

Comment: If it's an existing user who has logged out, they should be taken straight in (that part already works with the code I have). If it's a new (never before signed up) user, they should be taken to the signup screen.

Comment: @KingTim , Are you going to use FirebaseDB along with Authentication ?

Comment: The login credentials are the Facebook login credentials which (in Firebase) ties back to a Firebase user with a uid. So yes, those are the credentials. The problem here is that if they logged out, tapping it should not authenticate immediately and be brought into the app - that would defeat the purpose of logging out at all! Logging in without providing credentials is generally not a good idea. Are you aware of any apps that do that (outside of auto-filled username/pw combos)? I know that if I log out of my banking site, it will not let me back in without entering my username and password.

Comment: Yes, Tinder does that. There is no username/password, just tap on the Facebook button and if you're signed up, you get authenticated by Facebook then go right back in where you left off. If you're a new user, you're taken to a setup screen. That's what I'm going for. And I agree in this scenario logging out is relatively pointless, however this is not a banking app and nobody is in any real danger is someone else accesses their account!

Comment: @JenJose Yes, I use Firebase DB

Comment: So after the native FB login, show the set-up page of the app and then do the Firebase authentication and then use the UID for storing details on FiRDatabase. Getting me ?

Comment: But yes, this set-up screen is must then and if the user has quit app in the middle of this process , then his account won't be created on Firebase

Comment: You there ? if this is what you want, I will post that as an answer.. i am in dire need of upvotes ;)

Comment: Do you mean, in viewDidLoad of the setup screen, check if the user is authenticated with Firebase? i.e. add the `FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener` block (in my question), which is currently already in viewDidLoad of the login screen, to the setup screen? I tried it and new users are still bypassing the setup screen after tapping the Facebook button. They're authenticated with Facebook, then go straight into the app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145155/discussion-between-jen-jose-and-kingtim).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user clicks on the FB Login button :

-> Do the native FB login . (like what you are doing now)

-> do the firebase authentication.

-> But additionally, check whether the Data exists in the FirDatabase

```
      FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "name"]).start { (connection, result, err) in

            let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current()
            guard let accessTokenString = accessToken?.tokenString else {return}
            let credentials = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessTokenString)

            FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    return
                }

                self.checkDataExistsinfirDataBaaseForUID(user.uid){
                  loginStaus in
                  if(loginStaus){
                        // logged in
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToRooms", sender: nil)
                   }else{
                        // not logged in
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showSetupScreen", sender: nil)
                   }
}

            })

            if err != nil {
                return
            }
        }
```

Ideally, after the setup page you must be adding the set-up information in the FirebaseDatabase under the node users -> uID. So check whether any such node is present in this method.

```
func checkDataExistsinfirDataBaaseForUID(_ uid: String, completion: (result: Bool) -> Void) {
 let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid)

    ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        completion(snapshot.exists())
     })
}
```

Test cases :

1. If a brand new user taps the FB login button on the login screen, they'll be taken to the setup screen.

Fulfilled.

2. If an existing, but logged out, user taps the FB login button, they'll bypass the setup screen and go to the first page in the app.

After fb login-> firbase authenticateion ->Firdatabse node check -> if Returns true->login to app

3. If an existing user signs up then never logs out, they'll never see the login or signup screen again.

By using your process of cehcking,  `FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener {}`

Comment: Winner! This seems to be working for all use cases. Thanks!

Comment: glad it helped !