# Firebase Auth, how to know new user signed up, rather than existing user sign in?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

My use case is that I want to ask newly signed up users to enrich basic info like their names.
So I was hoping to do it like:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    if (some indicator tells me it is newly signed up user)
        {redirect to a form to fill in more info}
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

I checked the doc, and could not find anything related to this...

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I store the user in the DB with a `onboarded` field. I check this to make sure they were onboarded before they continue. There is no "out of the box" functionality in the auth state for this.

Answer (score 51):

Since version 4.6.0: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#4.6.0
You can get if a user is new or existing in 2 ways:

1. If you are getting back a `UserCredential` result, check `result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser`
2. Check `firebase.auth().currentUser.metadata.creationTime === firebase.auth().currentUser.metadata.lastSignInTime`

Previously you had to do that on your own and keep track of the user using Firebase Realtime Database. When a user signs in, you check if a user with the specified uid exists in the database or not. If the user was not found, it is a new user, you can then add the user to the database. If the user is already in the database then this is a returning existing user. Here is an example in iOS.

[Handing Firebase + Facebook login process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184770/handing-firebase-facebook-login-process)

Example for using `result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser`:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then((result) => {
  console.log(result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. that's the only idea, too, so far. I was wishing auth itself offers an API to do it :) after all, in Firebase auth console, it has a list of signed up users. It would be so great if I could directly check the uid against the list in the auth console. but just wishful thinking...

Comment: Firebase added a flag to check if a user is new or existing: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#4.6.0

Comment: I found it here : task.getResult().getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser()

Comment: Is it me or is the API for `.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser` cannot be found anymore? @bojeil can you post a concrete example? Much appreciated

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: `firebase.auth().currentUser.metadata.creationTime === firebase.auth().currentUser.metadata.lastSignInTime`

**IT IS NOT WORKING!!** Every time when I reload page after signup it return true.

Comment: Can you help me out, i have a doubt when we sign in in the data we get returned have a user object and an addittional user objects both have almost similiar datas and user object have a uid field where as additionaluserinfo has id field , whats the difference between these id and uid ?anybody can help ?

Comment: firebase.auth().currentUser.metadata works for me so far with google login. Doesn't really matter with Facebook because firebase overrides Facebook with google login.

Comment: @knotri lastSignInTime is only updated if signout/signin interval is more than 2 minutes: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/662

Comment: Update in Nov 2021. 

firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then((result) => {
  console.log(result._tokenResponse.isNewUser);
});

Comment: Now with Firebase v9 you need to call `getAdditionalUserInfo(result).isNewUser` https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#getadditionaluserinfo

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is do things in the callback function of the signup function, the signup function do return a promise. You can do something like this:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(function(user) {
    //I believe the user variable here is the same as firebase.auth().currentUser
    //take the user to some form you want them to fill
})
.catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

[image]

However, I don't really recommend doing it this way because the client side code can be unreliable. Think about what if a user suddenly disconnect before they can fill the form. Their data will be incomplete in your database. So if you do it this way, do set a flag in your user's profile when they submit the form so that you know who filled detailed information and who didn't.

Another better way to do this is using firebase cloud functions. You can have code like this in your cloud functions. Cloud functions are written in node.js so you don't need to spend time on another language.

```
exports.someoneSignedUp = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
  // you can send them a cloud function to lead them to the detail information form
  //or you can send them an welcome email which will also lead them to where you want them to fill detailed information
});
```

This way is much better because you can safely assume that your cloud functions server will never be down or compromised. For more information about cloud functions you can refer to their doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events

Answer (score 1):

You can check the sign-in methods the user has (if any). If there are none, it is a new user.

```
// Fetch sign in methods (if any)
Auth.auth().fetchSignInMethods(forEmail: userEmail!) { [self] signInMethodsArray, error in
        
    // Check for error and alert user accordingly
    if let error = error {
        // handle errors
    }
    // Email accepted.
    // Check if new or returning user.
    else {
            
        if (signInMethodsArray == nil) {
            // New User
                
        }
        else {
            // Returning User
                
        }
    }
}
```

This is Swift (iOS) code, but the concept is the same across languages.