# Firebase user registration with google

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am trying to implement google sign-in feature in my app. I have followed this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin), problem is - if I use previously used google account, it is not showing an error like "the e-mail is already registered in this app". As a result, previously stored data with the account are deleted & the google account is registered again. Here is my code :

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        int coins = 100;
                        String name, email;
                        name = user.getDisplayName();
                        email = user.getEmail();
                        //updateUI(user);
                        storeUserCredentials(name, email, coins);
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Error : " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}

public void storeUserCredentials(String name, String email, int coins){
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    User user = new User(name, email, coins);

    mDatabase.getReference("Users")
            .child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .setValue(user)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Registration Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException){
                            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "The email is already used", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
}
```

What is wrong with my code, please explain.

Comment: Are you asking why this code succeeds? `mDatabase.getReference("Users")
            .child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .setValue(user)`

Comment: Actually I'm asking why storeUserCredentials() gets called. As the google account is already registered, storeUserCredentials() should not be called again. Probably I am missing something, but I cant figure it out.

Comment: You're calling `signInWithCredential`, which successfully completes then the user is signed in.

Comment: The method is called because ``signInWithCredential`` is triggered always, not 
only the first time the user logs in the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `signInWithCredential` the SDK returns a task that successfully completes when the user is signed in. Since you call `storeUserCredentials` on that condition, it will get called each time the user is signed in. This is actually a quite normal flow.

If you want to detect if this account is new to Firebase Authentication, you can check the creation time of the user. See [Firebase Auth, how to know new user signed up, rather than existing user sign in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45529839/firebase-auth-how-to-know-new-user-signed-up-rather-than-existing-user-sign-in)

If you want to detect whether you've already seen the user before, you'll want to check in the database before calling `storeUserCredentials`. But what you now have is a pretty idiomatic flow, since it for example ensures you store the up-to-date display name each time you ask the user to sign in.