# How to determine whether it's a SignUp or SignIn in Passwordless Auth from Firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I want to know this because this will determine the user flow for me in my react-native app.
Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/egp6bq/how_to_determine_whether_its_a_signup_or_signin/

Comment: This should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45529839/firebase-auth-how-to-know-new-user-signed-up-rather-than-existing-user-sign-in If it doesn't, update your question to show the [minimum code that reproduces what you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).