# React + Firebase Form Validation if user does not exist

Tags: reactjs, firebase, reactstrap

Currently I am working on a login modal that will authenticate the user using the firebase function. If they do not exist, I plan on using the reactstrap library to turn the boxes red and make a message like "Invalid email or password." However, I am a newbie to React and am having a lot of trouble getting the return object/number from the firebase function when, in the email form, I call onAuthenticate={firebase.authenticateUser}. How can I get the return object (-1 if the user does not exist), check it, and either close the modal or turn it red with react strap if the user does not exist?

Snippet of my firebase function followed by my React modal below.

'''

```
exports.authenticateUser = async (email, password) => {
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(() => {
      const success = {
        success: true,
      };
      alert('User exists.');
      console.log('user exists');
      return success;
    })
    .catch((error) => {

      alert('Invalid email or password.');
      console.log('no user');
      return -1;
    });
};
```

---

```
return (
  <Modal
    title="Please enter log-in information"
    onClose={onClose}
    footer={modalFooter}
    titleBackgroundColor="#FFFACD"
  >
  <FormGroup>
    <Label for="examplePassword">Invalid input</Label>
    <Input invalid />
    <FormFeedback tooltip>Oh noes! that name is already taken</FormFeedback>
    <FormText>Example help text that remains unchanged.</FormText>
  </FormGroup>
    <EmailForm
      onAuthenticate={firebase.authenticateUser}
      const returnObj = {firebase.authenticateUser}
    />
  </Modal>
);
```

'''

Comment: Have you tried looking at the docs or for similar questions before posting this question?

Answer (score 0):

Your user should be the value then gets returned from the promise. Try the following, it should log your user if they were signed in or log an error if there was a problem.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(user => console.log(user))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

If the user does not exist and there is no error this method will create the user.

It's a little unclear, has that solved your problem or are you looking for a way to validate if this is a user's first sign in? As in the user does not already exist in your database?

If this is what you want to do the signup method will not help you. Please refer to [Firebase Auth, how to know new user signed up, rather than existing user sign in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45529839/firebase-auth-how-to-know-new-user-signed-up-rather-than-existing-user-sign-in) instead